# Is there performance benefit in using temporary object?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-asio

I'm reviewing [HTTP Server 3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_3) example on Boost's website. There is following code in [connection](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server3/connection.cpp) class:

```
boost::tribool result;
boost::tie(result, boost::tuples::ignore) = request_parser_.parse(request_, buffer_.data(), buffer_.data() + bytes_transferred);
```

where `parse` declared as

```
template <typename InputIterator>
boost::tuple<boost::tribool, InputIterator> parse(request& req, InputIterator begin, InputIterator end)
```

I believe the goal was to copy returned value of `tribool` to local variable. But what is the point of doing it via temporary object (`boost::tie`) if one could write something like

```
boost::tuple<boost::tribool, char*> result = request_parser_.parse(request_, buffer_.data(), buffer_.data() + bytes_transferred);
// Our tribool is available via result.get<0>();
```

?

Comment: Probably Yes, if the temporary objects are automatic.

Comment: the temporary is most likely optimized away by the compiler

Comment: @JonathanWakely, doesn't `boost::tie(result, boost::tuples::ignore)` create new temp object whose `operator=` is called ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry - but it's only a tuple of references, so very lightweight and likely to be optimized away anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The benefit is not performance, it is practicality and readability: since you are not interested by the second object returned by `parse`, there is no need for keeping it. It is better to ignore it entirely and only get the result you are effectively interested in, namely the `tribool`. The following code, which uses `result`, will be much clearer.

In fact, when a function returns multiple data, it is often useful (in terms of readability) to "split" it to get the individual elements separately. For instance, consider [`std::set<T>::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert), which returns an iterator to the element as well as a boolean indicating whether it was newly inserted. Which of the following code do you find clearer:

```
std::set<int> s;
std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator, bool> res = s.insert(42);

if (res.second)
{
    doSomething(res.first);
}
```

vs

```
std::set<int> s;
std::set<int>::iterator itInsertedElement;
bool isNewlyInserted;

tie(itInsertedElement, isNewlyInserted) = s.insert(42);

if (isNewlyInserted)
{
    doSomething(itInsertedElement);
}
```

In my opinion, the latter is easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

It's only a semantic consideration I think.

1. The second element of the result is explicitly ignored, much more obvious that a trailing `.get<0>()`
2. The `result` variable is only bound with the *useful* part, and no other variable is required.

Performances here should not be affected as the compiler will treat it as:

```
 boost::tuple<boost::tribool, char*> __tmp = request_parser_.parse(/**/);

 boost::trilbool result;
 boost::tie(result, boost::tuples::ignore) = __tmp;
```

and the optimizer will then take care of eliminating the cruft and reducing that as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I think they use `tie` mainly for convenience. If you don't need `InputIterator`, just the `tribool` value, why would you want to create named variable?

This:

```
boost::tribool result;
boost::tie(result, boost::tuples::ignore) = request_parser_.parse(request_, buffer_.data(), buffer_.data() + bytes_transferred);
```

becomes this:

```
boost::tuple<boost::tribool, char*> results = request_parser_.parse(request_, buffer_.data(), buffer_.data() + bytes_transferred);
boost::tribool result = boost::get<0>(results); // or you can use boost::get<0>(results) everywhere you use it.
```

And you have on stack totally useless `results`.

Temporary value returned from `boost:tie` will be probably optimized by a compiler, so there shouldn't be any memory overhead.

Comment: Well, in this case get `get<0>` could be directly wrapped around the call to `parse`. However I suspect consistency is the point here, because that only applies to cases where you only need one of the returned elements.

Comment: By the way the `get<0>` should be called unqualified. It will be found via argument-dependent lookup and that way it will not need to be changed when the tuple is replaced by `std::tuple` (C++11).

Comment: Ruslan used `boost::get` so did I. Problem with wrapping `parse` with `get<0>` would be when you for some reason start needing the second value. With `tie` it would be a cosmetic change. With wrapping not so much.

Comment: I agree. The tie is better for consistency with all other calls that return tuples.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's any measurable performance difference (certainly not compared to the IO cost) but it's more convenient to simply refer to `result` rather than using `get<0>()` to get it out of the tuple.